# How to plot multiple dataframes to the same plot axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes, with unique x and y coordinates, and I want to plot them in the same figure.
I am now plotting two dataframes in same figure as such:

```
plt.plot(df1['x'],df1['y'])
plt.plot(df2['x'],df2['y'])
plt.show
```

However, pandas also has plotting functionality.

```
df.plot()
```

How could I achieve the same as my first example but use the pandas functionality?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To plot all columns against the index as line plots.

```
ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax)
```

A single [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) (not `subplots=True`) returns a [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes), which you can then pass to the second dataframe.

To plot specific columns as `x` and `y`. Specifying `x` and `y` is required for scatter plots (`kind='scatter'`).

```
ax = df1.plot(x='Lat', y='Lon', figsize=(8, 8))
df2.plot(ax=ax, x='Lat', y='Lon')
```