# Multiple Scatter plot on single chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Note : this is not bar chat it is scatter char,**
some solutions are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270301/matplotlib-multiple-datasets-on-the-same-scatter-plot) but they do not work, I have categories on one axis

```
ax=df_a.plot(y='y', x='x' , kind='scatter',  color='#FF7F50', figsize=(7,4), label='a')
df_b.plot(y='y', x='x'  , kind='scatter',ax=ax, label='b' )
#plt.legend(loc='upper left');
plt.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to have separate blue and orange line for each category like in multiple barcharts
[like this](https://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdpydoc/images/multistackbar.png)

**Reproducible example**

```
    data  = [['tom', 10], ['tom', 15], ['juli', 14],['juli', 16],['tom', 30] ]
    data1 = [['tom', 15], ['tom', 34], ['juli', 25],['juli', 15],['juli', 19] ]

    df1= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['month', 'val'])
    df2= pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['month', 'val'])
    ax =plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
    
    
    ax=df1.plot(y='month', x='val' , kind='scatter', color='#FF7F50', figsize=(12,6), label='df1')
    df2.plot(y='month', x='val'  , kind='scatter', ax=ax, label='df2' )
```

Comment: Plots usually represent the data. What about the data you have? Have you checked it thoroughly? Have you clearly set which variable to be represented by which axis, in this case Y-axis and X-axis?

Comment: y= chategories, x= numerical values, df_a and df_b have common categories and some available in only either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot two pandas dataframes in one scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344222/plot-two-pandas-dataframes-in-one-scatter-plot)